# Read NFC cards with ACR 1252u on Android

Tags: android, tags, nfc, smartcard-reader, pcsc

We have a ACR 1252u NFC card reader. We want to read/write NFC cards on Android with this device. The problem is that this device is not seen as a NFC device but as a USB device instead. Therefore native Android NFC can not be used. Currently we are able to detect the device and to trigger an event by adding or removing a card. But we are neither able to read nor to write a card. In the documentation we found some HEX codes that are transmitted to the device, but we did not figure out how they work in order to read/write cards. Also on the net we found some example codes using other ACR devices but obviously they are not compatible to our one.

I am looking for any working examples in order to get the ACR1252u reading/writing NFC cards on Android.

Comment: You might be interested in this: https://github.com/skjolber/external-nfc-api (disclaimer: commercial product)

Answer (score 0):

The reader is a USB CCID (chip card interface device, see http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/) device. Hence, you need to implement the PC/SC abstraction layer (see http://www.pcscworkgroup.com/specifications/overview.php) or use some ready-made library in order to send smartcard commands to that reader.